# Error del proveedor de WMI del servidor de informes

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

Acabo de instalar reporting Services en mi PC y quiero conectar con el servidor correspondiente. Como se muestra en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero me muestra el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
No se puede conectar a DESKTOP-SNMV9QJ.
INFORMACIÓN ADICIONAL:
Error del proveedor de WMI del servidor de informes:
Espacio de nombres no válido Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.RSClient)
Espacio de nombres no válido  (System.Management)
```

Estuve buscando alguna solucion en internet y me indicaron que vea si el servidor de informes esta funcionando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Mira esto: https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/325353/how-to-set-wmi-namespace-security-in-windows-server-2003

Comment: El articulo que me envia no es una solucion especifica para mi problema. Que usuario o grupo debo agregar para solucionar mi problema con SQL Server?